# How to add custom error responses in Http4s?

Tags: scala, http4s

Whenever I hit unknown route in my http4s application it returns 404 error page with *Content-Type: text/plain* and body:

> Not found

How can I force it to always return body as JSON with *Content-Type: application/json*?

> {"message": "Not found"}

I figured out that when I assembly *httpApp* I can map over it and  "adjust" responses:

```
val httpApp = Router.publicRoutes[F].orNotFound.map(ErrorTranslator.handle)
```

where `ErrorTranslator` just detects responses with status code of client error and *Content-Type* which is not *application/json* and then just wraps body into JSON:

```
object ErrorTranslator {

  val ContentType = "Content-Type"
  val ApplicationJson = "application/json"

  private def translate[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect: Sync](r: Response[F]): Response[F] =
    r.headers.get(CaseInsensitiveString(ContentType)).map(_.value) match {
      case Some(ApplicationJson) => r
      case _                     => r.withEntity(r.bodyAsText.map(ErrorView(_))) //wrap reponse body into enity
    }

  def handle[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect: Sync]: PartialFunction[Response[F], Response[F]] = {
    case Status.ClientError(r) => translate(r)
    case r                     => r
  }

}
```

**It works, but I wonder if there is maybe some less convoluted solution?**

It would be also great if a solution could "translate" other errors, like **400 Bad request** into JSON, similarily to presented code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also make it with value and `mapF` function:

```scala
val jsonNotFound: Response[F] =
  Response(
    Status.NotFound,
    body = Stream("""{"error": "Not found"}""").through(utf8Encode),
    headers = Headers(`Content-Type`(MediaType.application.json) :: Nil)
  )
val routes: HttpRoutes[F] = routes.someRoutes().mapF(_.getOrElse(jsonNotFound))
```

Comment: I think it's cleaner and shorter that my approach, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have defined your routes in a similar fashion, then you can add a default case statement

```
 HttpRoutes.of[IO] {
   case GET -> Root / "api" =>
        Ok()

   case _ -> Root =>
        // Your default route could be done like this
        Ok(io.circe.parser.parse("""{"message": "Not Found"}"""))
}
```

Comment: `case _ -> _` seems to work, but still it would properly handle other error codes like **400**.